# passing obj to obj using Object.assign

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So i have a little encounter I can't seem to know whats the problem because i can't seem to get the `vm.dataUpdate.length` its returning me an **undefined** value.

```
function massUpdate() {
  vm.dataUpdate = Object.assign({}, vm.leaveList);

  console.log(vm.dataUpdate.length); // returning undefined

  for (var x = 0; x < vm.dataUpdate.length; x++) {
    console.log(x);
    if (vm.dataUpdate[x].actionStatus === 'edited') {
      vm.dataUpdate[x].leaveStatus = vm.dataUpdate[x].action.actionName;
      console.log(vm.dataUpdate = vm.dataUpdate[x]);
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

**vm.leaveList** value

```
[
{
    "_id": "5a0e86e1cd39a911e3be8252",
    "comment": "\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.\"",
    "leaveSupervisor": "Barrack Obama",
    "leaveDays": "2",
    "leaveType": "Sick Leave",
    "fullName": "michelle obama",
    "toDate": "2017-11-17T16:00:00.000Z",
    "fromDate": "2017-11-16T16:00:00.000Z",
    "user": "admin123",
    "__v": 0,
    "leaveDateCreated": "2017-11-17T06:51:13.570Z",
    "leaveStatus": "Pending Approval"
},
{
    "_id": "5a0ea449cd39a911e3be8253",
    "comment": "my birthday",
    "leaveSupervisor": "Barrack Obama",
    "leaveDays": "1",
    "leaveType": "Birthday Leave",
    "fullName": "michelle obama",
    "toDate": "2017-11-20T16:00:00.000Z",
    "fromDate": "2017-11-20T16:00:00.000Z",
    "user": "admin123",
    "__v": 0,
    "leaveDateCreated": "2017-11-17T08:56:41.060Z",
    "leaveStatus": "Cancelled"
}]
```

Any Suggestions are welcomed.
Thanks

Comment: What is `vm.leaveList`? Does it have a `.length`?

Comment: Why are you using `Object.assign` at all here?

Comment: "*`vm.dataUpdate = vm.dataUpdate[x]`*" - are you sure you want to do that? And why did you put the assignment in a `console.log` statement?

Comment: `vm.leaveList` is an obj that has two values. @Bergi i used Object.assign too bind it to a new one so the `vm.leaveList` wont change in the UI.

Comment: @Bergi sorry i've **updated** my post now;

Comment: @Priz Given that you never assign to properties of `vm.dataUpdate`, the `Object.assign` is pointless. Notice that it does not make a deep copy.

Comment: @Bergi so this approach is not good ? can you recommend like the right way ?

Comment: @Priz I don't know what the code is *supposed* to do so I cannot suggest the proper approach. It sounds like you want something like `vm.dataUpdate = vm.leaveList.map(o => Object.assign({}, o, {leaveStatus: o.actionStatus == "edited" ? o.action.actionName : o.leaveStatus}))` though - notice `Object.assign` is used to copy the individual elements, not the whole array.

Comment: @Bergi oh okay thanks anyway its already working if i use directly the `vm.leaveList.length` downside is its already changing the **UI** side even though its not updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass **an array** to Object.assign.
See the following code:

```
var arr = [1,2,3]

var a = Object.assign({}, arr)
var b = Object.assign([], arr)

console.log(a) // { '0': 1, '1': 2, '2': 3 }
console.log(b) // [ 1 , 2 , 3 ]
```

**EDIT**

Because you are using angular, you can try also **[angular.copy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy)** it makes a deep copy of your object (array in this case) so you can avoid side effects when changing the properties of vm.dataUpdate

```
vm.dataUpdate = angular.copy(vm.leaveList)
```